# Memory leak in cls-hooked or wrong use?

Tags: node.js, express, cls-hooked

The following code increases memory usage until crash:

```
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
async function t2() {
}

async function t1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    httpContext.ns.run(t2);
  }
}
t1();
```

run it with: node --inspect --max-old-space-size=300 ns

The problem: The namespace _contexts map is never cleaned up.

There is a function destroy(id) inside cls-hooked/context.js but that it is never called.

I tried also ns.bind, ns.runPromise (which does a ns.exit()) and ns.bind

How can I delete the contexts after a run is finished?

The code:

```
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
function t2() {
}

async function t1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    httpContext.ns.run(t2);
  }
}
t1();
```

works.

The code:

```
const httpContext = require('express-http-context');
async function t3() {
}
function t2() {
  t3();
}

async function t1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    httpContext.ns.run(t2);
  }
}
t1();
```

has the memory leak again.

The cls-hooked async_hook method init() adds the context to the _contexts map.
The cls-hooked async_hook method destroy() deletes the context from the _contexts map.

The problem is that destroy is never called.

Is this a bug in cls-hooked or an incompatibility to the current async_hooks?

Comment: it was supposed to not be cleaned since you will rely on that namespace.

It can be cleared manually via
`cls.destroyNamespace(name)`

or 

`cls.reset()`

Comment: When I run in parallel one or more http request with express and the httpContext middleware is attached to the express server, can I still clear/reset the namespace? In async I never know when a http request is ongoing. Also express-http-context middleware is also only doing ns.run(). Who is ever cleaning the express-http-context ?!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of how `express-http-context` is implementing the `cls-hooked`

However, before you start your `express`, you should have created a namespace, and  that namespace will be the context where everything will be saved and retrieved. 

It is all referenced via AsyncResource that is handled by node.js (Technically you can implement it via AsyncLocalStorage using the newer node version).

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/16998
There were some discussion on the garbage collection for destroyed events.

Maybe you can try to loop and see if there are any memory issue

Comment: Memory Issue when you keep on saving a lot of stuff into the context, and see if it get wipe when event is destroyed.

The current test you do is just creating a new `context`, which is kind of like object that is used to stored stuff. Context is never destroyed unless it is specified. However item inside context can get wiped (I need to confirm this, will do some test later)

Comment: const nsid = 'a6a29a6f-6747-4b5f-b99f-07ee96e32f88';
const ns = cls.createNamespace(nsid);

/** Express.js middleware that is responsible for initializing the context for each request. */
function middleware(req, res, next) {
        ns.run(() => next());
} Thats how express-http-context integrates into the expess server. No cleanup

Comment: How can I delete one context? ns.run returns the context but there is no visible method on the context to delete it from the ns

Comment: The problem is that inside cls-hooked the async_hook init adds the context to its _contexts map in some init() method and would delete it from the map on some destory() method. The cls-hooked also manage the contexts with enter(context) and exit(context) in its _set array. On enter  context is pushed and on exit context is popped.  So the problem I have is that the context is never removed from the _contexts map.

Comment: Changing t2 to a sync function resolves the problem. Only that this is not possible in the project. Almost everything is async

Comment: The memory leak is again there, when t2 is sync but calls an empty async function

Comment: I need some time to investigate this. If I remember correctly, we're responsible to ensure there are no object referencing the item in `context` that you want garbage collector to clear it for you. 

Changing to sync is definitely not the solution here.

I will try to come up with something for us to have a valuable discussion. But I would suggest you to play directly with either `AsyncLocalStorage` or `AsyncHooks`

https://nodejs.org/api/async_hooks.html

Answer (score 5):

As pointed out to OP, the usage is definitely incorrect.

OP should only execute `ns.run()` once, and everything within that `run` will be of the same context.

Look at this example of proper usage:

```
var createNamespace = require('cls-hooked').createNamespace;
 
var writer = createNamespace('writer');
writer.run(function () {
  writer.set('value', 0);
 
  requestHandler();
});
 
function requestHandler() {
  writer.run(function(outer) {
    // writer.get('value') returns 0
    // outer.value is 0
    writer.set('value', 1);
    // writer.get('value') returns 1
    // outer.value is 1
    process.nextTick(function() {
      // writer.get('value') returns 1
      // outer.value is 1
      writer.run(function(inner) {
        // writer.get('value') returns 1
        // outer.value is 1
        // inner.value is 1
        writer.set('value', 2);
        // writer.get('value') returns 2
        // outer.value is 1
        // inner.value is 2
      });
    });
  });
 
  setTimeout(function() {
    // runs with the default context, because nested contexts have ended
    console.log(writer.get('value')); // prints 0
  }, 1000);
}
```

Furthermore, the implementation inside `cls-hooked` do show that context is destroyed via async hook callback `destroy(asyncId)`

`destroy(asyncID)` is called after the resource corresponding to `asyncId` is destroyed. It is also called asynchronously from the embedder API emitDestroy(). Some `resources` depend on garbage collection for cleanup, so if a reference is made to the resource object passed to `init` it is possible that `destroy` will never be called, causing a memory leak in the application. If the resource does not depend on garbage collection, then this will not be an issue.
https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked/blob/0ff594bf6b2edd6fb046b10b67363c3213e4726c/context.js#L416-L425

Here is my repo for comparison and test-run of memory usage by bombarding the server with tonnes of requests using `autocannon`
https://github.com/Darkripper214/AsyncMemoryTest

Based on the test, there is a negligible increase in the utilization of `heap` (As expected, as we're processing HTTP requests).

### Memory Utilization of CLS-Hooked & Async-Hook

### Purpose

The repository is a miniature test to see how is memory utilized when using `cls-hooked` and `async-hook` to pass context within `Node.js`.

### Usage

1. `npm run start` for CLS-hooked server **or** `npm run async` for Async-hook server
2. Go to Chrome and paste `chrome://inspect`
3. Click `inspect` to access to Dev Tools of the server

[image: devtools]

4. Go to `memory` tab, you may  take snapshot and inspect the `heap` before, during and after bombarding the server with requests
5. `node benchmark.js` to start bombarding server with requests. This is powered by `autocannon`, you may want to increase `connections` or `duration` to see the difference.

### Results

#### *CLS-hooked*

| Stat | 1% | 2.5% | 50% | 97.5% | Avg | Stdev | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Req/Sec | 839 | 839 | 871 | 897 | 870.74 | 14.23 | 839 |
| Bytes/Sec | 237kB | 237kB | 246kB | 253kB | 246kB | 4.01kB | 237kB |

Req/Bytes counts sampled once per second (Note that this is ran with debugger attached, performance per second would be impacted)

13k requests in 15.05s, 3.68 MB read

[image: cls-hook]

[image: cls-hooked graph]

#### *Async-Hook*

| Stat | 1% | 2.5% | 50% | 97.5% | Avg | Stdev | Max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Req/Sec | 300 | 300 | 347 | 400 | 346.4 | 31.35 | 300 |
| Bytes/Sec | 84.6kB | 84.6kB | 97.9kB | 113kB | 97.7kB | 8.84kB | 84.6kB |

Req/Bytes counts sampled once per second (Note that this is ran with debugger attached & plenty of `debug()` messages to show how it `store` is destroyed, performance per second would be impacted)

5k requests in 15.15s, 1.47 MB read

[image: async]

[image: async-graph]

*Edit 1*

OP is complaining on the length of `_context` which is set every time a `namespace.run()` is executed. As highlighted earlier, the way OP is testing is not correct, as it is running on a loop.

The scenario that OP is complaining will only occurs when `namespace.run()` execute some callback that is or contain an `async function`.

```
async function t3() {} // This async function will cause _context length to not be cleared
function t2() {
  t3();
}
function t1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    session.run(t2);
  }
}
t1();
```

So why _context is not cleared? This is because `async function t3` won't be able to be run in the node.js `event loop` as the `synchronous for loop` is continuously running, hence the near-infinite appending of item into `_context`.

So to prove that this is due to this behavior, I've updated the repo to include a file `cls-gc.js` that can be run using `npm run gc`, which explicitly run garbage collection in between, and garbage collection won't affect the length of `_context`.

The length of `_context` will be long during execution of `t1()` and `t2()` as both is synchronous. However, the length of `_context` will be about right after the `setTimeout` callback is called. Please use debugger to check for this.

Length of `_context` will be available at the `session`

```
// process.env.DEBUG_CLS_HOOKED = true;
('use strict');
let createNamespace = require('cls-hooked').createNamespace;
let session = createNamespace('benchmark');

async function t3() {}
function t2() {
  t3();
}
function t1() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    session.run(t2);
    try {
      if (global.gc) {
        global.gc();
        console.log('garbage collection ran');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('`node --expose-gc index.js`');
      process.exit();
    }
  }
}
t1();

function t5() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    // Check the _context here, should have length of at least 500
    session.run(t2);
    try {
      if (global.gc) {
        global.gc();
        console.log('garbage collection ran');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('`node --expose-gc index.js`');
      process.exit();
    }
  }
}
t5();

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('here');
  // Check the _context here, length should be 0
  session.run(t2);
}, 3000);
```

Comment: So the solution is to reverse any httpContext.set() httpContext.set(x, undefined) calls to clear the link to own objects to not  increase the heap by dangling contexts?

Comment: ns.run() is done for every http-request once express-http-context  is used. The _contexts map does not show up in async or namespace but in Objects. In the example code these Objects. The Objects  have a distance up to the number of ns.run(). With max-old-space-size=100 you can execute 48k ns.runPromise with 3 empty nested async functions before the GC aborts. With one empty async function and ns.runPromise you can reach 100k ns.runPromise calls. With 2 nested async you reach 66k. This means the more async you have the earlier the memory is killed. So about 800Bytes per async

Comment: Thanks for the benchmark repo! I will play around with it. How can I call emitDestroy() on the the cls-hooked async resource?

Comment: Realistically speaking, you shouldn't be running that much `ns.run()` anyway.

The issue is actually how `cls-hooked` implement the `ns.run()` to get the behavior of nesting of context.

Look at this part of the code 
https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked/blob/0ff594bf6b2edd6fb046b10b67363c3213e4726c/context.js#L86-L113

In order to enable this behavior, we have to keep track of all context, which is stored in `_contexts`.

While you're looping to infinity, this `_contexts` variable will grow in size till ti fails. This is not memory leak

Comment: This is just like you're pushing a gazillion item into an array.

After a request is fully run through, this variable will be cleared by the garbage collector anyway. 

I don't really see a scenario where you'll be running that much `ns.run` on a single node server that quickly.

Comment: The cleanup does not happen because all context's are linked directly to the previous context through __proto__ which links to the context object created by the previous createContext by ns.run. The depths is 60000 after using ns.run() every 10 seconds for 7 hours. Of course with a lot (uncountable) of nested async functions. This is unnecessary. I have reduced the problem by not using individual httpContext.set(). I use only one httpContext.set() to keep an "global" object that I can cleanup.  Could you have a look in the links between the context and why using a map and not an object?

Comment: Also there is a performance degeneration. Every 1000 ns.runPromise with an async function that is not completely empty are 20ms slower than the previous 1000. After 10000 the next 1000 cost 182ms while the first 1000 cost 22ms.  This happens when the async function was defined with one argument and this agrument is used like async t2(l) { if (l>1){}}.  However. the number of nested async don't change that.

Comment: can you share the code of the test you do `ns.run()` at 10s interval for 7 hours?

Comment: Map have its advantages when it comes to lookup, it is just an implementation details. Object works fine too.

Comment: Also there is a performance degeneration. Every 1000 ns.runPromise with an async function that is not completely empty are 20ms slower than the previous 1000. After 10000 the next 1000 cost 182ms while the first 1000 cost 22ms.  This happens when the async function was defined with one argument and this agrument is used like async t2(l) { if (l>1){}}.  However. the number of nested async don't change that. BTW: With just one httpContext.set() a context costs 56 bytes but that adds up to 8MB after 2520 ns.runPromise in (7h every 10 seconds)

Comment: Can you share the complete code of the said test? So I can try it on my end.

Comment: Its the same first code block from my question. Just change t2 to __async function t2(l) { if (l>1) {}}__. And add for the  for loop a console.info with a delta time  every 1000 ns.run. Like __if (i%1000===0) { console.info(Date.now()); }__ BTW: I use node 14 LTS

Comment: Update: Also exchange ns.run by ns.runPromise to not have pending promises

Comment: `namespace._contexts.delete(asyncId)` << This is run via `destroy` hook.

I just ran another test (warmed up)`11k requests in 300.94s` , The starting heap snapshots is 6.8MB, ran up to 7.0MB around 70% into the test, then back to 6.8MB a few seconds after the test.

Comment: The problem with spamming `ns.run` in a loop is that your `AsyncResource` never get the chance to be destroyed, and the program is already over when the it is up for destroy

Comment: Using ns.runPromise waits for the Promise and so is not spamming. The use of -max-old-space-size=100 limits the heap and enforces GC to run before it kills node because of out of memory.

Comment: Please look at the edited part of the answer, it is still because `ns.run` is not used in a way that it is supposed to.

Comment: The performance issue with the many runs comes from __let context = Object.create(this.active ? this.active : Object.prototype);__ replacing it by __let contest = {...this.active};__ solve that but the memory leak is still there. The object distance in a heapdump is then constant 8 instead of 60000

Comment: I exchanged  this._contexts = new Map() by this._context = {} and used this._contexts[asyncId]  and delete this._context[asyncId]  in addition to  context={..this.active} and now it works forever (of course after I add the wait ns.runPromise(..))

Comment: After 900k await ns.runPromise() calls from the code in my question (takes like 10 seconds) there are still only 5000 contexts in a heapdump. The retainer is the ns this._contexts with a distance of 5 and 6

Comment: I saw your comment at `cls-hooked`.

You can try to remove the `await` inside `ns.run` and it will fail, since the event loop don't ever get to run.

However with `await`, the `destroy` hook will have the chance to run.

Add a debug inside the `destroy` hook in context.js of `cls-hooked`

https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked/blob/0ff594bf6b2edd6fb046b10b67363c3213e4726c/context.js#L416-L424

`destroy(asyncId) {
      currentUid = async_hooks.executionAsyncId();
      debug1(`deleteHookRan here`) // here
      namespace._contexts.delete(asyncId);
    }
  });`